# How about the converse of the abelian factor group?

Tags: group-theory

If G is abelian then factor group G/H is abelian.

How about the converse of this statement?

Is it true?

Comment: Absolutely not.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: What are the factor groups of $S_3$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, depends. If you say "abelian for all subgroups $H$", then $\{1\}$ is of course a subgroup of $G$ and $G/\{1\} \simeq G$, so there is nothing to say there.

If you say "abelian for some subgroup $H$", then of course there are counter-examples. An easy one is take any group $G$ and $H = G$ : the group $G/G \simeq \{1\}$ is always abelian but $G$ might not be.

There is actually a subgroup of $G$ denoted by $[G,G] = \langle \{ [x,y] \, | \, x,y \in G \} \rangle$ where $[x,y] \overset{def}= xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ and $[G,G]$ is the subgroup of $G$ generated by these elements $[x,y]$. It is an easy exercise to show that $[G,G] \trianglelefteq G$ and $G/[G,G]$ is abelian, since saying that $G/[G,G]$ is abelian is essentially asking that $[x,y] = 1$ for all $x,y \in G/[G,G]$, but this is just true by construction. The group $G/[G,G]$ is called the "abelianization of $G$" and is the largest such abelian quotient of $G$, in the sense that if $G/H$ is abelian, then $H \supseteq [G,G]$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: The last case is the one I want. Yes I have a normal subgroup, element are commutators. Then $G/H$ is abelian. I want to show that $[x,y]=1$ for all $x, y\notin H$ but in $G$.

Comment: Can you give me an idea to construct that $[x,y]=1$? Is that for all $x, y \in G/[G,G]$ or $x,y \in G$?

Comment: @Patrik Da Silva I couldn't prove the statement which you have stated, $G/[G,G]$ is abelian is essentially asking that $[x,y]=1$ for all $x,y∈G/[G,G]$. Can you give an idea to proof this?

Comment: @Ryan : Take two elements of $G$, say $x,y$ ; look at their image in the quotient group $G/[G,G]$. Call them $\overline x, \overline y$. The projection map is a group homomorphism, hence $[\overline x, \overline y] = \overline x \overline y \overline x^{-1} \overline y^{-1} = \overline{xyx^{-1}y^{-1}} = \overline{[x,y]}$. What can you conclude from this? My last statement about $[G,G]$ being the smallest subgroup of $G$ such that $G/H$ is abelian also follows from this computation.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is your favorite nonabelian group, then $G/G$ is the trivial group!

Also, if $H$ has prime index $p$, then $G/H\simeq\Bbb Z_p$.